# Is there anyway to have different destination name of the installing file at than the source name?

Tags: install4j

I want to have different file name  at the destination side after installing it. Is there anyway to do it? I did not get that option in the Add Files and Directories action under Define Distribution tree. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The "Install files" action has a "Directory resolver" script to change the installation directory for each file, but there's no facility to change the file name.

You would have to use a "Move files and directories" action for that purpose.

Comment: I have two files with the same name (in a different directory) which need to be installed in the same directory but installed name shall be different. How I can achieve this. One way is to install the 2nd file in a temp directory and then move the file to the destination folder with its final name . At last to delete the temp folder created. if there is any other method available then suggest.

Comment: If you want to change the name of a file with respect to the name in the distribution tree, then yes, you would have to rename it after the installation.